# Using Java to convert PDF to XML

Tags: java, xml, pdf, itext

I'm trying to create a prototype to convert a PDF file to an XML file. The result is a little strange, all the characters becomes symbols. I think the bug is where the `StringBuffer` takes the data from the byte array. Can somebody with Java knowledge please help?

This prototype software is using the `iText` API. To read the PDF file, we have used the`PDFReader` class. The data is first converted into a byte array, then with the use of `Stringbuffer`, it will again converted into string. Then we have used `StreamResult` wich acts as an holder for the transformed result in XML.

After that, the `Transformer` class processes XML from a variety of sources and writes the transformation output to a variety of sinks. Then `TransformerHandler` listens for SAX `ContentHandler`, parse events and transforms them to a result.

The methods `startElement()` and `endElement()` of `TransformerHandler` class have created the tags in the xml file. The Parser invoked `startElement()` method at the beginning of every element and `endElement()` at the end of every element in the XML document.

```
import com.lowagie.text.*;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.*;

public class Cp2x {

        static StreamResult streamResult;
        static TransformerHandler handler;
        static AttributesImpl atts;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

                try {
                        Document document = new Document();
                        document.open();
                        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:\\helloworld.pdf");
                        PdfDictionary page = reader.getPageN(1);
                        PRIndirectReference objectReference = (PRIndirectReference) page
                                        .get(PdfName.CONTENTS);
                        PRStream stream = (PRStream) PdfReader
                                        .getPdfObject(objectReference);
                        byte[] streamBytes = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
                        PRTokeniser tokeniser = new PRTokeniser(streamBytes);

                        StringBuffer string_buffer = new StringBuffer();
                        while (tokeniser.nextToken()) {
                                if (tokeniser.getTokenType() == PRTokeniser.TK_STRING) {
                                        string_buffer.append(tokeniser.getStringValue());
                                }
                        }
                        String test = string_buffer.toString();
                        streamResult = new StreamResult("test.xml");
                        initXML();
                        process(test);
                        closeXML();
                        document.add(new Paragraph(".."));
                        document.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
        }

        public static void initXML() throws ParserConfigurationException,
                        TransformerConfigurationException, SAXException {
                SAXTransformerFactory tf = (SAXTransformerFactory) SAXTransformerFactory
                                .newInstance();

                handler = tf.newTransformerHandler();
                Transformer serializer = handler.getTransformer();
                serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
                serializer.setOutputProperty(
                                "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
                serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                handler.setResult(streamResult);
                handler.startDocument();
                atts = new AttributesImpl();
                handler.startElement("", "", "Document", atts);
        }

        public static void process(String s) throws SAXException {
                String[] elements = s.split("\\|");
                atts.clear();
                handler.startElement("", "", "Note", atts);
                handler.characters(elements[0].toCharArray(), 0, elements[0].length());
                handler.endElement("", "", "Note");
        }

        public static void closeXML() throws SAXException {
                handler.endElement("", "", "Document");
                handler.endDocument();
        }
}
```

Comment: "The result is a little strange, all the characters becomes symbols" seems like encoding issue. pass encoding while converting byte array to String. may use StringBuilder instead of StingBuffer depending on use case.

Comment: You're also ignoring all the content that is present in XObjects; how are you going to capture these in XML? Also: you're only reading String objects, and you're not taking into account the actual order of the text. Why are you using an obsolete version of iText? The current version of iText has a much better parser. It can even convert a Tagged PDF to an XML file using the TaggedPdfReaderTool: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=281 (which obviously only will produce XML if your PDF was tagged).

Answer (score 1):

As @sudmong says, there is an encoding issue: The`PRTokeniser`should not be used to read strings from **inside** page content streams, it works properly only outside them because it assumes a special character encoding while the encoding of strings inside page content streams completely depends on the encoding of the current font at that step of the content description. Cf. [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) sections 7.3.4.2 *Literal Strings* for strings outside content streams and 9.6.6 *Character Encoding* for strings inside content streams.

As @BrunoLowagie points out, you furthermore completely ignore that page content is not only inside the immediate page content stream but also in XObjects referenced from there, cf. [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) section 8.10 *Form XObjects*. He also points out that strings in the content stream need not be in the reading order, cf. [ibidem](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) section 9.4 *Text Objects*.

You also ignore that the value of the Contents entry of the page dictionary can either be a stream or an array of streams:

> The value shall be either a single stream or an array of streams. If the value is an array, the effect shall be as if all of the streams in the array were concatenated, in order, to form a single stream. Conforming writers can create image objects and other resources as they occur, even though they interrupt the content stream. The division between streams may occur only at the boundaries between lexical tokens (see 7.2, "Lexical Conventions") but shall be unrelated to the page’s logical content or organization. Applications that consume or produce PDF files need not preserve the existing structure of the Contents array. Conforming writers shall not create a Contents array containing no elements.

*section 7.7.3.3* Page Objects *in [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)*

If you really really want to program a parser yourself, you had better study [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) first.

Otherwise look at the`...text.pdf.parser`package of iText which already is quite a good tool for parsing PDF content. If you feel like it, you may help improve it.